# How to change the format of datatimepicker result?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, datetimepicker

**I need to enable users to select a date from a calendar and then show the selected date on the console.**

Usign the following code I can show a datetimepicker and receive the selected date. When the type of variable is String it shows the following output

```
2013-03-27T00:00:00+11:00
```

When the type of variable is Date it shows the following output

```
null
```

How can I receive the result in yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy ? so it should be 2013-03-27 or 27-03-2013
I am not interested in using subStr is there any other method?

JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%> 
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <sx:head/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>

....
<sx:datetimepicker name="Sdate"
                              label="MyDate"
                              displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                              value="todayDate"/>
.....
```

Class

```
public class Datepicker{
      private String sdate;
     ... getter and setter go here ...
}
```

Comment: see my EDIT in anwser to parse String to perticular format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is typo problem

You JSP contains `sx:datetimepicker name="Sdate"` this shold be `sx:datetimepicker name="sdate"`

but the property in `private String sdate;`

You can use datatype is Date only in controller like this `private Date sdate;`

EDIT:

```
 String str = "2013-03-27T00:00:00+11:00";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat parseFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            //SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+hh:mm"); 
            Date date = parseFormatter.parse(str);

            String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: but as I explained in the question it shows the date but I just need to change its format

Comment: change the formatter object to this SimpleDateFormat formatter
   = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: I am getting '27-Mar-2013'. Can I get the serial number of the month. That is in place of Mar, I need 03.